# How to check duplicate from Strings given by user

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I am writing a code for checking duplicate which is typed by user. When the user type the second duplicate, the program will stop and warn the user of the duplication. My logic is I will put given words to the `ArrayList` and then check the next given word in the current `ArrayList` if it is already there or not.

```
public class RecurringWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Type a word: ");
            String word = reader.nextLine();
            words.add(word);
            int i = 0;
            if (words.contains(words.get(i+1))) {
                System.out.println("You gave the word " + words.get(i+1) + " twice");
            }
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: traverse the list with an iterator... and then check for duplicates... try it some more... it will help you.. since you are new to java

Comment: list.contains(word) is case-sensitive... If you want case insensitive, use string.equalsIgnoreCase(string)

Comment: Why don't you put them in a `Set<String>`?

Comment: Use a HashSet<String> to filter out duplicates.

Comment: Thanks you guys for quick reply. I am currently reading all and figure out the advanced stuff. As I said, I am new to Java, for about 1 week. Kudos for all of you :D

Answer (score 0):

You need a little reorganizing and logic check. If you want to stop when user tries to add the same word twice, then stop and don't add it at all to the list, you then won't have to keep any index at all.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.nextLine();
    if (words.contains(word)) {
       System.out.println("You gave the word " + word + " twice");
       break;
      }
    words.add(word);  
 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. Your answer is quite understandable and suitable to my level. It helps me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try something as listed below

```
  ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
   while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.nextLine();

    if (words.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println("You gave the word " + words.get(i+1) + " twice");
    }else{
       words.add(word);

    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. For your requirement there is no need to use an iterator `i`.
Additional see the comments:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.nextLine();
    if (words.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println("You gave the word " + words + " twice");
        break; // end the programm if the word exists twice
    }
    words.add(word); // add the new word after the check.
}
```

in your example the user can only type in one word, after that the programm ends.

```
words.get(i+1)
```

will result in an `Exception` because the element will never exists.
you start at element 0 not 1.

Furthermore I suggest you to use a Set if it is an invalid case to have the same word twice:

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
```

The `Set` will never contains two Strings that are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String word = reader.nextLine();
        if (words.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println("You gave the word " + word + " twice");
            break;
        }
        //This is only reached when `word` is new. 
        //Add it to the list to keep track of it for later possible duplicates
        words.add(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Set, its special for unique values. add() method return boolean: true if added, false if not.
example:

```
Set<String> example = new HashSet<String>();
String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "a"};
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    boolean res = example.add(arr[i]);
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

output will be:

```
true
true
true
true
false
```

**UPD**

Your example:

```
public class RecurringWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Type a word: ");
            String word = reader.nextLine();
            if(!words.add(word));{
                System.out.println("You gave the word " + word+" twice");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecurringWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String word = reader.nextLine();
        String[] words = word.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (countMap.containsKey(words[i])) {
                countMap.put(words[i], countMap.get(words[i]) + 1);
            } else {
                countMap.put(words[i], 1);
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
                System.out.println("You gave the word " + entry.getKey()
                        + " : " + entry.getValue() + " many times");
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

If you just want to have `twice` check then try with below snippet:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecurringWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String word = reader.nextLine();
        String[] words = word.split(" ");
        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (wordsList.contains(words[i])) {
                System.out
                        .println("You gave the word " + words[i] + " : twice");
            } else {
                wordsList.add(words[i]);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```